# after clicking a button, the checked check box in a list should disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a web app, using Django as backend and normal HTML as frontend.

In a HTML page, there's a checkbox list.
After some checkboxes are checked and a button is clicked, the checked checkboxes( `<input type="checkbox" name="course" value="{{course}}" >{{course}}` in my case) should disappear and other checkboxes should auto fill the blank.
How could I do that in JavaScript?

```
        <div><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="optradio" value="notspecific"> select all courses below.</div>
        {% for course in query_results_course %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="{{course}}" >{{course}}
        {% endfor %}


<button class="button" type="button" onclick="send_disappear()">send_disappear</button>

<script>
    function send_disappear() {
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: What does `"auto fill the blank"` actually mean?

Comment: @Professor Abronsius   if some checkbox disappears and leaves a blank line, the below one should move up to fill the blank line

Comment: Your question does not match the provided code. Where are *those* new checkboxes from? What is `toggle(this)` ? where is it defined? Where's the code? And where's the code for `send_disappear` ? I see only an empty function.

Comment: Rather than using a `BR` tag after each checkbox control the layout with CSS then when a checkbox is removed you do not need worry about the `BR` creating a blank line

Comment: Also, basic HTML, you should not have two Action Elements inside a single `<label>`. There's also no need to use `<br>` after a `</div>` A DIV element is already a block-level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` to control the container elements.

Read more about `flexbox` layout : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Best practice: add `for` attribute to each `label` you dynamically generate to associate with checkbox element.

You need to look for `input[type=checkbox]:checked` elements - Refer JS section.

```js
let send = document.querySelector("#send");
send.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let selectedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".courses input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  selectedCheckboxes.forEach(function(item) {
    item.parentElement.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.courses {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* control the flex direction ROW|COLUMN */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* for spacing only */
}

.courses label {
  margin: 5px 0; /* for spacing only*/
}

.courses input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 10px; /* for spacing only*/
}
```

```html
<div class="courses">
  <label for="react"><input type="checkbox" id="react">React</label>
  <label for="js"><input type="checkbox" id="js">JavaScript</label>
  <label for="php"><input type="checkbox" id="php">PHP</label>
  <label for="py"><input type="checkbox" id="py">Python</label>
</div>
<button id="send">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a very simplified version of your HTML you can use CSS to inject the appearance of the `line-break` by using a little trick of `display:table` and some simple Javascript to explicitly select any `checked` checkboxes and either remove them, add a new class, change the display property .... or other action

```js
const bRemove=false;

document.querySelector('button.button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach( input=>{
    if( bRemove )input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    else {
      input.disabled=true;
      input.style.display='none';
     }
  })
})
```

```css
[type='checkbox']{display: table;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="6" />

<button class="button" type="button">send_disappear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I mean the checkbox item disappear(both the checkbox and the checkbox text disappear.